# extract the row of text files based on minimum value on particular column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i have many text files(.txt) files inside the directory as given below:

```
Data
       data1.txt
       data2.txt
       data3.txt
       .........
       .........
       datan.txt
```

where data1.txt,data2.txt....datan.txt contains the structure like as below:

```
mengo   1.0  2.0 5.0 1.0 
banana   1.0  2.0 5.0 0.5 
frog    1.0  2.0 5.0 2.3 
python   1.0  2.0 5.0 1.9 
anaconda   1.0  2.0 5.0 1.1 
cow   1.0  2.0 5.0 1.5
```

I need to extract the complete row which contain the minimum value in the 5th column

for example for above example answer should be

```
banana   1.0  2.0 5.0 0.5
```

and then i want to save the extracted file in a separate directory with the same file name.

For example

```
    New_data
           data1.txt
           data2.txt
           data3.txt
           ........
           ........
           datan.txt
```

I tried the code below for doing the same but it doesnot show any results...hope some expert may help me.Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /home/lijun/Data/*.txt
do
awk '{if $5=min}' $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done using single awk like this:

```
cd /home/lijun/Data

awk -v destdir='../New_data/' 'NR == 1 || $5 < min { min=$5; rec=$0 }
END { print rec > (destdir FILENAME) }' *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort`:

```
sort -nk5 file.txt | head -1
banana   1.0  2.0 5.0 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use sort command to sort base on column number 5 of file and print only that line.

```
#!/bin/sh
des_dir="your_destination_dir"
cd /home/lijun/Data/
for file in *.txt
do
output=$(sort -n -k 5 $file | head -1)
echo $output > $des_dir/$file
done
```

Comment: your_destination_dir//home/lijun/Data/input_data/data1.txt: No such file or directory
 error

Comment: I think we should cd to /home/lijun/Data/ and perfrom for loop

Comment: please have a look https://i.fluffy.cc/3t8l9hw85k53Rl31KjZsBPB8BRF8j5QX.html

Comment: you should replace des_dir variable with obsolute path of your separate directory (example: des_dir="/home/lijun/New_data")

Comment: can u please show me using my data in the links provided

Comment: For example you staying in directory ext, my terminal as below: 

`ls`
input_data  test.sh
`cat test.sh` 
#!/bin/sh
des_dir="../output_data"
cd input_data
for file in *.txt
do
output=$(sort -n -k 5 $file | head -1)
echo $output > $des_dir/$file
done

`mkdir output_data`
`./test.sh` 
`ls output_data/`
data1.txt  data2.txt  data3.txt
`cat output_data/data1.txt` 
/home/lijun/data 1.0 2.0 5.0 0.1